# What is the best way to transfer selected MySQL data every minute to another MySQL server?

Tags: php, mysql

Well I'm looking for a way how I can transfer selected MySQL data from one server to another every minute or at least every few minutes. Here an example:

(Connect to the source SQL server and select the needed data)

```
SELECT name, email, online, session FROM example_table WHERE session!=0
```

(Process the data, connect to the external target SQL server and INSERT/REPLACE the data)

I want to transfer ONLY the output of the query to the target server which has of course a fitting table structure.

I have made already a simple PHP script which is being executed every minute by a cronjob on Linux but I guess that there are performance wise better ways, nor it supports arrays right now.

**Any kind of suggestions / code examples which are Linux compatible are welcome.**

Comment: If you're really only trying to copy a subset of data, the current method is actually already pretty sane.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what data it is you're trying to transfer, but luckily MySQL supports replication between different servers. If you save the data on the local source server and set up the target server to fetch all updates from the source server, you'll have two identical databases. This way, you won't need any scripts or cronjobs.

You can find more information at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication-howto.html.

Comment: Well I'm trusted with MySQL Replication but I want to select in general just 100~ entries average from a table with 300.000+ entries and I don't need most additional columns for the webserver.


The idea to transfer the data into a own table first and replicate only this single table is good though, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good open source replication engine:

http://code.google.com/p/tungsten-replicator/